# How to add an image to a Teams App manifest for a local app

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-appstudio

For a local App that will be only available on our own tenant (so no publishing to the MS app store), I want to display an image / image carrousel on the app's "splash screen", just like the image below:

[image]

The image markdown seems to be supported, however when I add the image markdown, like so:

```
![No Image](https://test.com/test_picture.png)
```

It does not show the image, but the alternative text and a link to the image:

[image]

How can I display images like the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not part of the manifest. You can set this while submitting your app to the app store. Please reach out to teamsubm@microsoft.com for any further queries on this.

Comment: can you confirm that for a local (tenant) teams app this is totally not possible?

Comment: This is not possible, only app submission team had access.